# Exclude rows if a column has different values for a combination of other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

```
c1  |   c2  |  c3
----|-------|----
A   |   Z   |  false
A   |   Z   |  true
P   |   Y   |  false
Q   |   X   |  true


Output
---------------
P   |   Y   |  false
```

For the given table above, I'm trying to write a sql query that meets the below conditions :

- If for a combination of `c1` and `c2`, `c3` has both `false` and `true` values - ignore those
  rows.
- Also ignore those rows whose `c3` value is only `true`, for a combination of `c1` and `c2`
- Return those rows whose combination of `c1` and `c2` has the only value `false` in `c3`

###### What I tried :

To solve this problem, I tried looking at self-join and tried using intersect / except operators but that didn't help in any form.

Comment: Can this be rephrased as "only c1/c2 where c3 is 0?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `GROUP BY` and `CAST`. First you can look for c1 and c2 combinations that occur only once, then you can filter for combinations that have a c3 of false.

```
SELECT c1, c2, MIN(CAST(c3 AS INT)) AS c3
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY c1, c2
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c3) = 1 AND MIN(CAST(c3 AS INT)) = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, [boolean is just tinyint(1)](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-boolean/) and [true and false are just 1 and 0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/boolean-literals.html). You can group by c1, c2 and check that the sum of c3 is 0.

```
select c1, c2, sum(c3)
from test
group by c1, c2
having sum(c3) = 0
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=57d75774962451175049f468c718e285)

Comment: I've updated the question - `c3` is actually a boolean field

Comment: @WAS This solution should work with booleans too. Unless you're storing them as varchar/string

Comment: @PhilCoulson I have a lot more experience with `SQL Server` vs `MySQL` but I would expect that you can't `SUM` a `BIT`.

Comment: @DerrickMoeller You can. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=57d75774962451175049f468c718e285 You can even multiply boolean by 1 to get 1 and 0